# Need to update shell scripts so they can run in different *nix flavors

Tags: linux, shell-script, portability

I have a bunch of ksh and csh scripts that need to be updated to run in different *nix flavors (red hat linux, hp ux, solaris). 
The shells are mounted in the home of each of our servers and we need to have them working in each env.

We have issues with some particular commands that are not found under linux.
For example scripts use `nawk`, which should be replaced by `gawk` on linux.

Scripts also use `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` because on solaris `grep` can't take the -q (quiet) option, but linux's grep can and in this env `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` doesn't exist.

I don't want to touch every script, so I'm looking for a more global solution.

I've tried to setup aliases, that works. But only in interactive mode. Looks like it isn't advised to use aliases in scripts...

I can add symlink in the system dirs but then I'll need admin rights to manage this 'mocking' setup and the our setup is not portable anymore...

I'm not used to system admin, so I can miss a standard solution for this kind of need.

What can I do to have portable script without to rewrite them all ?

Comment: Use the same base system; Touch all the scripts and include switches; setup symlinks etc. so it does feel similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right approach is to stick to `POSIX` compliant commands (i.e. use `awk`, not `nawk` or `gawk`, `grep`, not `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`), options and syntax and set your `PATH` that way:

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH):$PATH
```

or on Solaris if using the legacy Bourne shell:

```
PATH=`getconf PATH`:$PATH
```

and that's it, your scripts launched for there should run unmodified. Avoid using the `#!/bin/sh` shebang though, which despite popular belief is **not** `POSIX` compliant. Just use no shebang at all. You might use `command -v sh` so see what `POSIX` shell is available on your machine.

However, it looks like you want to keep your non portable scripts unchanged. Then you might keep the previously suggested approach for commands using the `POSIX` syntax and add a front end for the non portable commands to be handled on other OSes. As your scripts are using either Bourne or Csh style shells, aliases and functions won't be portable so better to use your own wrapper scripts library that you put in front of your `PATH`. For example:

sh / ksh / bash / ... :

```
PATH=~/bin:`getconf PATH`:$PATH
```

csh :

```
set path = ( ~/bin `getconf PATH` $path)
```

-

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cd ~/bin
cat > awk <<%
#!/bin/sh
PATH=`getconf PATH`:$PATH awk "$@"
%
ln -s awk nawk
ln -s awk gawk
```

Comment: this won't change the fact that there are part in code that call nawk wich is not supported by the linux env. For the shebang, it's too late: scripts contains it and it is required because some scripts are cshell, some others are kshell and the main shell is bash...

Comment: I'll probably use this solution for the grep issue, as there's no single solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In such case I use variables

```
AWK=awk
GREP=grep
```

then test for operating system

```
if [ $(uname -s) == "SunOS" ]
then
  AWK=/usr/bin/nawk
  GREP=/usr/xpg4/bin/grep
fi
```

(repeat for redhat, suse, hp-ux, aix)

and use variable after

```
if $GREP -q whatever /some/file
then
   $AWK -F: '{....}' /some/file
fi
```

this way I have only one script but usable in all hosts.

Comment: I really don't want to add this mess in all the scripts